# wp_enqueue_style in WordPress plugin class not working

Tags: wp-enqueue-style, wp-register-style

I'm trying to add a stylesheet for my plugin class settings page, but the CSS is not loading. I followed the 2nd example at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style to create this simple test code :

```
class MyTestPlugin
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
            add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'add_menu'));
            add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'register_plugin_styles' ));
    }
    public function register_plugin_styles() {
            wp_register_style( 'my-test-plugin', plugins_url('sbm-test.css', __FILE__) );
            wp_enqueue_style('my-test-plugin');
    }
    public function add_menu()
    {
            add_options_page('SBM Test Settings', 'SBM Test', 'manage_options', 'sbm-test', array($this, 'sbm_test_options'));
    }
    public function sbm_test_options()
    {
            echo "<p>SBM Test Options Page.</p>"; 
            echo "<p>" .  plugins_url('sbm-test.css', __FILE__) . " is not loaded.</p>";
    }
}

if(class_exists('MyTestPlugin'))
{
    $test = new MyTestPlugin();
}
```

The path to `sbm-test.css` is correct, but I think the function `register_plugin_styles` isn't being called. I have `WP_DEBUG_LOG` `true` but not seeing any errors in the log. I'm not sure why add_action isn't hooking it in so I'm hoping someone sees something I missed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IF you want the CSS to be in your plugin's settings page, you should be using this action: [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts), as the action you are currently using is [for the front end](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts#Description).

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'register_plugin_styles' ));
```